# How to get current method in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, logging, methods

I found the following code, which I guess goes in config/initializers/kernel.rb.

```
module Kernel
   private
   def this_method
     caller[0] =~ /`([^']*)'/ and $1
   end
end
```

For adding to the log, is this the preferred way to get the current method?

Thanks.

Comment: If using Ruby 1.9.x you could use the #__method__ like so `def foo; __method__; end; #=> foo`

Comment: When you call foo in that case, it will simply return :foo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems like a decent way to get the calling method and give you the ability to call `this_method` in your code to add to the log.

If you are using Ruby 1.9.2 you can call `__method__` instead and not worry about defining a special method to do so.